# How can I extract 12 bits from a 2 byte char array?

Tags: c++, char, bitwise-operators, bit

I am working on extracting data from binary files. One of the data values is packed into two bytes, but only 12 of the 16 bits contain the relevant information:[image: Packed data structure.]

Does anyone have a method to extract the 12 bits seen in this image? Let the two bits be stored in an unsigned char buffer[2].

Comment: Are you sure it's not `>>`?

Comment: I am pretty certain there are typos in this question.

Comment: Even with `>>`, this computation doesn't extract the 12 bits shown in the image (it extracts a different 12 bits and in a strange order).

Comment: There must be more information about what this data represents. Even if those are supposed to be right shift operators instead of greater than operators, the reconstruction of a 16-bit unsigned integer purely from the data would be `((buffer[0] & 0x0f) << 8) + (buffer[1])`. If this code is correct than there's more context that is missing.

Comment: Where did you find that code? It doesn't do what you say it does. Are you sure that the code refers to this particular data packet, or is it some other "extract twelve bits" code that you found?

Comment: This is buggy code.  Since you are not sharing where you _found_ this code, the answer may be "this code never worked" or it may be "you transcribed this code incorrectly".  We have no way to know.

Comment: You've edited this into a different question. You should instead post a *new* question so the existing comments and answers don't distract from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` does with respect to a `char` the same thing it does with any other type - it returns 1 if the left side is greater than the right side, and 0 if it isn't.

It doesn't make sense here.

If you copied this from the Internet, I suspect the author wrote `>>` but the formatting got messed up by the website at some point.